# Windows Sign-in options disabled - GPO enabled

Tags: windows, windows-11, active-directory, group-policy

So with the new update on Windows 11 23H2 there comes an issue regarding the Sign-in options in the settings, specific the "PIN" and "Fingerprint" or "Facial" options.

In my organisation the settings to use these features are enabled, i got a screenshot of the "Convenience PIN" Policy for you to better understand what I try to say.
The setting is enabled, I checked it using "rsop.msc". Biometrics are enabled aswell.

What am I doing wrong with the GPO's, I'am an Administrator in my company, so I can manage them if I misconfigured something.

Comment: If you're in a business environment I believe the additional sign in options have some additional requirements for configuration. It is the same UI, but you might be dealing with "Windows Hello for Business". What research have you done regarding any requirements for this to work?

Comment: @music2myear I get it to work, i disabled all settings from Windows Hello for Business in my GPO. Then chnaged it back to "Not Configured" and only enabled the following setting:
Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / System / Logon / Turn on convenience PIN sign-in -> ENABLED
Once i "gpupdate /force" my GPOs and restarted, I was able to use my PIN and fingerprint again.